# Why a Swing app stops my Java servlet?

Tags: java, swing, servlets

I have a Swing runnable app which updates messages, then I have a Java servlet that gets messages from Paypal IPN (Instant Payment Notification), when the servlet starts up, in the init(), I starts the Swing runnable app which opens a desktop window, but 30 minutes later an error in the Swing caused the servlet to stop, how can that happen ? Because the runnable is running on it's own thread, servlet started that thread, why an error in that thread will cause the servlet to stop ?

```
public class License_Manager extends JPanel implements Runnable
{
  License_Manager()
  {
    Do_GUI();
    ...
    start();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    // Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread : creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() { Create_And_Show_GUI(); } });
  }
}

public class PayPal_Servlet extends HttpServlet
{
  public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException
  {
    super.init(config);
    License_Manager.main(null);
  }

  protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException
  {
  }
}
```

And besides the error don't even have anything to do with my code, it looks like this :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 17 >= 0
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:427)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListModel.getElementAt(DefaultListModel.java:70)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paintCell(BasicListUI.java:191)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paintImpl(BasicListUI.java:304)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paint(BasicListUI.java:227)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:143)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:763)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1029)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:864)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:747)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:864)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5124)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:278)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1220)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5072)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4882)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:803)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:714)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:694)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(SystemEventQueueUtilities.java:128)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

---

Edit :

Thanks for all the replies, it seems starting a thread in init() is a bad idea, my original idea was, my Swing GUI app processes all the messages the servlet gets and writes to a folder and I can see the GUI working on the screen while the servlet gets the messages at the back end, they are related, so I run those two processes at the same time and starting the servlet will automatically starts the GUI for me too in the init(), now I may start those 2 processes separately so that no matter what happens to the GUI, the servlet won't stop !

Comment: @Frank: I *did* integrate PayPal's IPN with Java Webapps and I'm really confused by your question. You're running a Swing app *from a Servlet*? You're running a Webapp on a "headfull" system and that server pops up a Swing app when a PayPal payment is made!?

Comment: @Frank: Besides the fact that I really don't understand what you're trying to do, as far as I see from your question the *"Runnable is *NOT* run in its own thread"* [sic].  It is run on the EDT using SwingUtilities.invokeLater and your crash is happening on the EDT.  You're somehow screwing/locking the EDT.

Comment: @WizardOfOdds : Since you have done Paypal IPN, do you know why even after I took out the GUI app from my servlet, it still fails from time to time, when I first started it, I got a few messages, but after a while, it fails, why ? I used the sandbox to send test messages, is it not reliable ?

Comment: I hope that you are aware that in this case Swing runs at the **server** machine and not at the **client** machine? If your intent is to run it at the client machine, then look in the applet/webstart corner.

Comment: Yes, on my home notebook, which is acting as a server, so I can monitor the messaging activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems definitely wierd. Saw something similar on sun (now oracle) forums. No good answer on it till now. But may be you can get a clue as it seems the same problem
Link http://72.5.124.102/thread.jspa?threadID=5339908&messageID=10469703

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I'm stating the obvious, but it looks like you have a JList in your GUI, and its backing model is being emptied while it's being painted. It expects at least 18 elements, and shows that there are 0. Is there somewhere that you're modified the contents of the list outside of the event dispatch thread?